# Xcode Save for Enterprise or Ad-Hoc Deployment fails - "Code signing operation failed"

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, ad-hoc-distribution

Starting today, I can't export/save apps in .ipa. Every time I try, I get a message at the signing moment:

Invalid arguments were passed to codesign.  Arguments were: --sign 351424d48e1f5c926f2fc268f1a286d14faefb77 --force --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements,resource-rules /var/folders/nl/0q4kl6ws57j3cx3pbzgfqjph0000gn/T/8860C8DC-DF6C-425D-9ED6-643BCD543AB5-1576-0000059990815932/Test.app/Test

Were can be the problem?

How could I solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install some self-sign apps for resign cracked ipa??

if you did, I can help with it, Check out my fix [here](http://imi.im/post/2012-12-26/40046118177)

Comment: Don't have time to test this, but let's hope it's useful for someone else!